How to deserialize a YAML field that can be an object or a string
I am attempting to deserialize a YAML config that has mono/multilingual strings in multiple places, such as:
key1: File
# or
key2:
  en_US: File
  de_DE: Datei

Using kotlinx.serialization and charleskorn's KAML (which adds YAML support for the former), I want to deserialize this into objects such as:
@Serializable
sealed interface LingualString {
    // the actual code uses java.util.Locale; this is simplified
    operator fun get(locale: String): String
}

@Serializable
class MonolingualString(
    private val text: String
) : LingualString {
    override operator fun get(locale: String) = text
}

@Serializable
class MultilingualString(
    private val map: Map<String, String>
) : LingualString {
    override operator fun get(locale: String) = map[locale]!!
}

How do I write a KSerializer<LingualString> that can load such values from the config?

After some searching, I found that Content-based polymorphic deserialization may be able to handle this case.

Unfortunately, this is a JSON-only feature and KAML doesn't provide this kind of content-based polymorphism according to its documentation. It only provides "explicit polymorphism" in the form of !<type> and type:.
